# How do I import a Windows vista User Account on my partitioned drive?

Tags: users, system-installation

While I was installing Ubuntu it asked if I wanted to import a user from Vista.  I chose one but I do not know how to get to it or if it even was imported.

Comment: Nevermind, I have found it.  It only took a few minutes before my Drive appeared and I was able to access my files.

Comment: Did the import succeed? Or are you looking at your files *in your Windows system*? (Ubuntu gives you access to your Windows files whether or not you import them into your Ubuntu system.)

Answer (score 3):

According to the OP the import in fact worked:

> Nevermind, I have found it. It only took a few minutes before my Drive
>   appeared and I was able to access my files. – Austin Dec 3 '11 at
>   22:59

Answer (score 0):

If import worked you should see your Windows user data in your browser and in Documents , Pictures, other user data.